# Creating a Website With Minimum Bandwidth Cost

Tags: bandwidth

I am trying to come up with a website with minimum bandwidth cost:

Imagine that a user is tight in bandwidth, even loading a webpage is "expensive" for him. What if the webpages are saved in his computer. However, he needs to transmit and receive data like text and compressed media files.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can design an web page with Ajax, which will lower the loading time and cost. User can fetch multiple windows and content with must reloading.